# VirtualBox host-only networking fails on Ubuntu 11.10 host

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a new Lenovo Thinkpad 420s and I'm trying to get some VirtualBox VMs up and running (using Vagrant).  Everything works fine until I try to add host-only networking.  This is the failure I get in the terminal:

[image: host-only networking failure - terminal]

I set logging to debug and tried again.  [Here's a paste of the relevant portion of the log](http://pastebin.com/FLhQPG7F).

When I try to add host-only networks with the VirtualBox gui (File->Preferences->Networking->Add host-only networking), I get the following error message:

[image: VirtualBox gui host-only networking failure]

This error is occurring with three different virtual boxes, all Ubuntu 11.10 64bit guests, one of which I've run without issue on a Windows host and an OSX host.

Here is the Vagrantfile for the box I've successfully run on Windows and OSX:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-11.10"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://timhuegdon.com/vagrant-boxes/ubuntu-11.10.box"
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
  config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natnet1", "10.0.28.0/24"]
  config.vm.forward_port 80, 4567
end
```

I've tried two other boxes as well, one of which I built last night with veewee, all of which are getting the exact same error.

I've used rvm to install ruby 1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ], and I've got Vagrant running in its own gemset.

I've Googled quite a lot and haven't been able to find any resolution.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10405) of VirtualBox 4.1.12 (from the VBox apt repository).

I've removed VBox and then manually installed the previous version 4.1.10 and now everything works again.

Comment: Confirmed, it's a regression in 4.1.12, bugreport: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10405, forum link: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=48854#p222052

Comment: Seems like they have released a fix, but they haven't bumped the version number. Not a very good idea for package managers... deleting cache and reinstalling could work.